# How can I change array elements C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

How can I get array or array values from for-loop?

Example first outputs prints right solution, but second output prints just last line, last word of array.

How to get correct value for array from splitLine and save it in variable for using it later?

File text

```
Title:
```

> Here is my first line.
>       Here is my second line.
>       Here is my third line.
>       Here is my fourth line.
>       Here is my fifth line.

Code

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Array
{
    class Class
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(
                @"file.txt");

            string[] array = new string[] {};

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] splitLine = lines[i].Split();
                for (int j = 0; j < splitLine.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(splitLine[j]);
                    array = splitLine[j].Split();
                }
            }
            Array.ForEach(array, Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: array = splitLine[j].Split(); is not adding to array each iteration, it's setting the value of array. So yes, it sets the last line and then exits the for loop.

Comment: I recommend debugging this code -- you should see pretty quickly what's happening here. As @DavidThielen mentions, pay special attention to the line `array = splitLine[j].Split();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the 'array' variable to accumulated values from each string split operations, then you don't have it quite right.  As written your code only sets the 'array' variable to the last string split operations.  You should consider using a collection type like List as the type for your array.  Then call the Add method to add a single item or the AddRange method to add an enumeration (which can be an array).

Comment: Yes I know that `array = splitLine[j].Split();` is not right solution because it don't give array length. Also in for loop I cant change array size somehow. And also I dont want use list, because this can be done with an array, but I can't figure out how it should it be done.

Comment: In that case you will need to go through the contents of the file twice, once to determine the number of array elements needed, then once to fill in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReadAllLines()` method is already splitting your text into lines. I'm not clear if you want to split it further? If not, simply:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt");
lines.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Should output the lines to the console